# How to create a custom dialer using phonegap (Android and iOS)

Tags: android, ios, cordova, keypad

I would like to create a phonegap application which is basically a dialer that dials a number, based on the number from phone contacts. (I would be having a logic in the application, which basically adds some additional numbers to the existing number from contacts).

I know that I can access the contacts using http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#Contacts

But is there any plugin to dial a programmatic number, its available in android but I couldnt find one for iOS
https://github.com/sialam/PhoneGap-2.7-Android-plugins-to-make-a-phone-call

in Android I can give the [phonenumber] in cordova.exec(null, null, "PhoneDialer", "call", [phoneNmber]);

Is there any plugin for iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @joel do the following changes

1)Corresponding phone dialer.js
https://gist.github.com/rahulinaction/2703b8c6f30f5daa1732

2)Corresponding phonedialerh and m files
https://gist.github.com/rahulinaction/9337f8dd5618955d4762
 copy these files to  your plugins folder inside CordovaLib.xcodeproj  and add it to your CordovaLib.xcodeproj

3)Then in your Cordova.plist create a string in the Plugins Dictionary with key name as phonedialer and value PhoneDialer.Or if you have a config.xml add this 
plugin name="phonedialer" value="PhoneDialer" inside plugins tag.

4)Then you can call the following by this window.plugins.phoneDialer.dial(yourno)

As for the latest phonegap i think the commandline feature is quite easy as you dont have to do individual setups  for diff platforms.I dont know an alternative though.

Comment: thanx for the detailed description. Will try it out when I have access to a mac and get back. For now this answer will suffice

Answer (score 0):

This is a plugin you can use just that is updated for cordova 3.You might just have to do some changes in dialer.js for older phonegap version  https://github.com/j-mcnally/PhoneGap-ios-PhoneDialer

Comment: could you tell what changes I have to make in dialer.js since I am using cordova-2.4.0? I tried this plugin ( https://github.com/sialam/PhoneGap-2.7-Android-plugins-to-make-a-phone-call ) and it works for Android. Can I use its PhoneDialer.js instead of j-mcnally dialer.js? Also could you point to a tutorial to use latest Phonegap without the commandline, like how easy it is to setup Phonegap 2.4.0 as given here ( http://cleancodedevelopment-qualityseal.blogspot.com/2012/12/first-phonegap-app-with-android-using.html )